# Text animation like on the radio

Tags: android, android-animation

I have one question. It is possible to make the text animation like on the radio? (Spotify android app have it) I tried that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="6500"
    android:repeatMode="restart">
<translate
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"/>
```

but it doesn't work perfect. Maybe somebody had similiar problem? Hope you help me, nice evening. Thanks in advance :)

When the end of the text is going to the end of screen it doesn't go on the beginning of the screen but it waits on the rest of the text and later whole text animate again instead of doing it up to date. We can say the text is a whole and I would to split it.

Answer (score 1):

if i got your q right you mean text slide from left to right then repeat again .
this not need animation object already their option in TextView apply something called 
elipisize  with value "marquee"

```
 <TextView
   ....
   android:text="long text " 
   android:ellipsize = "marquee"/>
```